# Animate div to overlap on top of another div on click, then return to previous div on click

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to navigate between divs on click (sliding out from the side using animate). I've somewhat got it to work, but I need it to "start over" when you are back at the main menu, which it currently does not do.

Right now you can click the menu icon (which for some reason you have to click twice) to open the side menu. Then if you click on "More articles >" the next menu appears. Clicking the << arrows at the top takes you back to the main menu, BUT if you try and click on "More articles >" again, it doesn't open. Also, if you close the menu all together and try to re-open it, it does not work either...

Any suggestions on a better *cleaner* way to do this would be much appreciated. So far, this this is the code I'm using:

HTML

```
<div class="triggerBox"><a href="#" id="trigger">≡</a>
</div>
<div class="menu">
        <h2>Programs</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
        <h2>Pages</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="interior-trigger" href="#">Page with Children > </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
        <h2>College</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Full Site</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Apply</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="interior-menu">
        <h2><a id="back" href="#"><<</a>Articles</h2>

    <ul>
        <li>Article</li>
        <li>Article</li>
        <li>Article</li>
        <li>Article</li>
        <li>Article</li>
        <li>Article</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 body {
    font-family:"Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
.menu, .interior-menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    right:-360px;
}
.interior-menu {
    display:none;

.menu ul, .interior-menu ul {
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

And my script

```
// slide open and close the main menu
$("#trigger").click(function () {
    $(".menu").animate({
        "right": "0px",
            "width": 'toggle'
    },
    100);
});
//hide the interior menu
$("#interior-menu").hide();

//after clicking on a page with children, slide out the main panel
$("#interior-trigger").click(function () {
    $(".menu").animate({
        "right": "0px",
            "width": "0px"
    },
    30);

    //slide out the parent page's child menu 
    $(".interior-menu").animate({
        "right": "0px",
            "width": 'toggle'
    },
    30);
});
```

Please see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j4N38/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this...and I forked your jsfiddle so you can test it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZLHMf/

```
// slide open and close the main menu
$("#trigger").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".menu").animate({
        "right": "0px",
        "width": 'toggle'
    },
    100);
});
//hide the interior menu
//$("#interior-menu").hide();

//after clicking on a page with children, slide out the main panel
$('.menu').on('click', '#interior-trigger', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".menu").animate({
        "right": "0px",
        "width": "0px"
    },
    30);

    //slide out the parent page's child menu 
    $(".interior-menu").animate({
        "right": "0px",
        "width": 'toggle'
    },
    30);
});


// click the back button to reveal the slide main panel again
$('.interior-menu').on('click', '#back', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //slide out the interior panel
    $('.interior-menu').animate({
        "right": "0px",
        "width": "toggle"
    }, 30);
    //slide in the main panel again
    $(".menu").animate({
        "right": "0px",
        "width": '300px'
    },
    100);
});
```

Edit:

Have you thought about using CSS transitions? You can probably accomplish most of this without jquery, if you don't need to support IE <10.

Comment: I do have to support at least to IE8